# VT -x disabled and Java Virtual machine works

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine, bios

In Windows 10, the VirtualBox can not create a virual machine (ubuntu).
As you know,i need to change VT -x disabled to VT -x enabled in the BIOS.
My question is why the Java virtual Machine(JVM) is working correctly when VT -x was disabled.
And Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: the Java virtual machine doesn't use VT-X.

VT-X is an extension that makes it much more efficient to run a virtual machine using the Intel instruction set on a hardware machine using the Intel instruction set.  Since both the real and virtual instruction sets are the same, there are a bunch of performance optimizations you can make if the hardware supports it.

The Java virtual machine runs Java byte code on your real instruction set, typically using just-in-time compilation.  Since the instruction sets are not the same, VT-X is not generally useful to a JVM.